# Убрать подчеркивание ошибки в панели навигации и сайд баре

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Подскажите как и где настроить назойливое подчеркивание ошибок. Именно в:

1) В сайдбаре:

[image: Подчеркивание ошибок в сайдбаре]

2) В панели навигации (но не в самом редакторе):

[image: Подчеркивание ошибок в навигации]

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Профиль проекта можно попробовать перенастроить.